# DialogResult.Cancel on Form.ShowDialog() when switching to Desktop

Tags: c#, winforms, modal-dialog, showdialog

I am trying to show a UI (WinForms) via `result = new Form().ShowDialog()`. The dialog pops up, works as expected but when i press Windows + D to tab away, the `result` immediately returns `DialogResult.Cancel`. Is there any way to keep the Form open when i am switching to desktop?

If there are any more questions or if it is unclear, please ask.

Best regards

Comment: Do you have a keyboard accelerator which is using `D` in a Dialog's Button?

Comment: @Jimi No i don't, it is a basic Form with 2 buttons, one returning `DialogResult.Cancel`and one returning `DialogResult.OK`

Comment: Well, since Win+D does not close any dialog, there's *something* that triggers the Cancel Button Click event (it could also be a System HotKey). Try setting the `CancelButton` property of the Form to `(none)` and set the `DialogResult` in the `Button.Click` event, with: `this.DialogResult = DialogResult.Cancel;`. But keep it commented out, or set a BreakPoint there, and try again. Btw, you do know that an accelerator is defined by a letter prefixed by `&`. Not necessarily set on the Button.

Comment: @Jimi i tried your suggestion out but it does not work for me. the breakpoint is hit when i click on the button, but is not hit when i tab to my desktop but the `DialogResult` is still set somehow. I have looked at the HotKeys aswell, but could not find anything either. Guess it might not be possible then. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Since this happens, than it's possible :). If you have disabled the DialogResult related properties on the Form dialog (have you?), it's then triggered by the code the instanciate the Dialog. There's not enough code here to tell where/why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not come up with a solution for this exact problem. Therefore, to workaround, I used `Form.Show()` instead of `Form.ShowDialog()` and referenced the DialogResult property of the Form, rather than the return value of `Form.ShowDialog()`.